# Extracting a random word in a string

Tags: c++, string, random, extract, cpu-word

I would like to extract a random in a given line so I called a random number to use it as an index. But it keeps giving me an error.

```
terminated called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'.
```

I know it occurs because the index value is exceeded size of the string. But I can not find any mistake in my code.

```
do {
    int size = line.length();
    srand(time(NULL));
    index = rand() % size;
} while (isspace(line.at(index)));
```

This is a random number generator. I extract a line from a text file.

I used
    do { } while (isspace(line.at(index)));
because I do not want it to be space, in order to generate a random number again if it is space.

What I want is this.

0123456789

Example...        Index : 4

F---i----L        F : First, L : Last

```
if (index == 0) {
    while (!isspace(line.at(last + 1))) {
        last = last + 1;
    }
}

else if (index == (size - 1))) {

    while (!isspace(line.at(first - 1))) {
        first = first - 1;
    }
}

else {
    while (!isspace(line.at(first - 1))) {
        first = first - 1;
    }

    while (!isspace(line.at(last + 1))) {
        last = last + 1;
    }
}

for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    targetword += line.at(i);
}
```

This is how I calculate first and last index and print out the chosen word and it should not make any error...

please help me thank you

Comment: Note you should only call `srand()` once - this is the initial "seed" for randomness. If you repeatedly seed it the same way, you will repeatedly get the **same** "random" number back. Or better yet, use a more modern recommended way of handling random numbers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY

Comment: What happens, when the string does not contain any space? Your while loops increment last / decrement first until they are out of range.

Comment: Starting with C++11, STL has a new random number generator facility (header <random>), which is better than C's rand. You can read about it on the web, e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this loop (or any of the following in the posted snippet):

```
if (index == 0) {
    while (!isspace(line.at(last + 1))) {
        last = last + 1;
    }
}
```

There is no check of the increasing `last` beeing less than the size of the string *before* calling `std::string::at`, so an exception of type `std::out_of_range` will eventually be thrown.

Also, `std::srand` shouldn't be called repeatedly inside a loop, but only once. Even better if you could avoid using `srand` and `rand` at all, moving to the modern [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) facilities.

If the intent is to *"extract a random word"* from a string, you might split the original string into words and then choose one of those

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

// Split a string into a vector of words.
auto words_from(std::string const& src)
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    // A "word" can contain only alphanumerical characters. Your milage may vary.
    auto is_in_word = [] (char ch) {
        return std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
    };

    for (auto it = src.cbegin(); it != src.cend();)
    {
        auto first = std::find_if(it, src.cend(), is_in_word);
        if ( first == src.cend() )
           break;
        ++it;
        auto last = std::find_if_not(it, src.cend(), is_in_word);
        words.emplace_back(first, last);
        it = last;
    }

    return words;   
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize the pseudo-random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::seed_seq ss{rd(), rd(), rd()};
    std::mt19937 rnd_gen{ss};

    std::string source {"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."};

    // Split the original string into words
    auto words = words_from(source);
    if (words.size() == 0)
        return 0;

    // This will generate uniformly distributed indices in the correct range
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, words.size() - 1);

    // Print a random word
    std::cout << words[dist(rnd_gen)] << '\n';
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/11pc43GCBxbeO2Oz).